# Tabindex not in order

Tags: html, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility

With the following markup, I am access the first three elements in fine (remove button, description, & go button).

When I have two of these rows, the order after the first row go button skips to the next row's go button.

I have the tabindex="0" so it would follow the order of the page. I also tried many variations of tab order with no luck. Any thoughts?

```
<table class="table table-striped bookmarkListContainer">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="removeButton" data-bookmarkid="120" tabindex="0" aria-label="Remove Test module">
                <button><span class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span></button></td>
            <td tabindex="0">Overview<br><span class="greyText">Foundations</span></td>
            <td tabindex="0"><a data-bypass="true" href="/test/section/1/module/1/page/overview" class="openBookmark"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right">Go</button></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="removeButton" data-bookmarkid="121" tabindex="0" aria-label="Remove Test module">
                <span class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span></td>
            <td tabindex="0">Delivery Method - Tabs<br><span class="greyText">Foundations</span></td>
            <td tabindex="0"><a data-bypass="true" href="/test/section/1/module/1/page/1" class="openBookmark"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-small pull-right">Go</button></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have two `tabindex="0"` maybe that is the problem

Comment: Why do you need `tabindex` everywhere in the first place? Screenreaders already read a page from top to bottom, left to right without the need of this attribute and their users can also choose to tab through links and form elements if they prefer or even access a list of all headings and their content. Or landmark roles or tables or …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be missing **button** tags on the second "remove button".  So, change your mark up to:

```
<button><span class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span></button>
```

If you don't want to use the button markup for some reason, I would suggest using the following markup:

```
<span role="button" tab-index="0" class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></span>
```

For more about this, read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role

You still will not "see" the tab focus through in the browser with this markup.  I tested in Google Chrome and it doesn't really change the results in any way, but perhaps screenreaders will honor the tab-index setting.

As a side note, you should probably remove the `tab-index="0"` from the table cells.  That will just cause the cell to also be in the tab order, and what I *think* you really want is just the buttons.  Also, if you choose to use the button tags, by default, they will follow the tab order of the source, so you don't have to add the tab-index=0 to them.